# Google Cloud Messaging tutorial - messages don't send

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following [Google Cloud messaging tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start), I'm not exactly understang phrase:

> First, make sure your Server key (not the client API key in googleservices.json) is provided as the value of API_KEY in GcmSender.java.

So in order to run this sample, I need to write a server side? I thought that GcmSender.java already emulates server side of the application? Can someone clarify it?

Comment: You'd better use Firebase Cloud Messaging instead of Google Cloud Messaging. There is a separate tutorial for FCM [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: @MohanadMohie thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MohanadMohie you should instead use FCM.

> First, make sure your Server key (not the client API key in googleservices.json) is provided as the value of API_KEY in GcmSender.java

The GcmSender.java does emulate the function for sending a message. This only states that you should make sure that the API key you use is a valid Server Key.

And as per Server Keys go, there is already a note in the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) saying:

> Starting from Sept. 2016 new server key can only be created in the Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the Firebase console without affecting their existing configuration.

Plus, in FCM, you'll be able to make use of the Firebase Console to send push notifications.